# Download a remotes branch

Tags: git

When I execute `git branch -a` I have a lot of branchs in red who begin with `remotes/origin/...`

How can I download it as a local branch ?

Thx

Comment: How did you clone the repo?

Comment: @m0skit0 hmm, I don't remember with a `git clone` may be

Comment: Ok, is `git checkout` not working? What's the exact problem/error you're facing?

Comment: I would like to make a correct checkout on one of this branch

Comment: do you want to download or checkout a branch?

Comment: download then checkout :)

Comment: Sorry I'm not asking what you want to do, but is `git checkout` not working? If not, what's the exact problem/error you're facing?

Comment: try `git checkout your_branch`

Comment: `git clone` downloads all branches, unless you specifically tell it not to do that. So `git checkout <branchname>` does what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks `git checkout -b` seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `git fetch` to download anything/everything regardless of branches. You already did that though, I guess.

Do `git checkout remotes/origin/blabla` to do a (headless) checkout of one of them, or `git checkout blabla` which will automatically create a local branch for the remote branch if you do not have `blabla` yet.

Answer (score 0):

They are `red` because they are indicated as remote branches. There is nothing wrong with that. They will normally correspond to some branches in your local repository. You can check that with `git remote show <remote name>`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: "How can I download it as a local branch"

Comment: It answers the question because `remote` branches will be located on his local file system after he carried out `git clone` and he can verify the correspondence using `git remote show <remote_name>`